# VPS and Network firewalls opened, still can't connect

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall

I created a VPS on Oracle Cloud (Ubuntu Minimal image) and I'm trying to run a server on it.
I tried running a simple server command first to test connectivity:

```
 sudo python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

Ok, I get "serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 80".

Now I try to access it via browser and it times out. So, it must be the firewall..

So I disable all firewall rules usind the following commands:

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

and

```
sudo ufw disable
```

I try to connect again. Still, no luck. So it must be a network firewall on Oracle. I go to the Oracle configurations and I find the firewall and add the rule to open port 80, as follows:

[image]

I try to connect again. Still not connecting. I ran out of ideas. What could be going on?

Comment: Are you trying to access your machine off the LAN or wan?  If the LAN, what does Oracle have to do with it?   On your server, if you open a terminal window and type "sudo tcpdump -n -i any port 80" and then on a different machine on the LAN make web requests, what do you see?   TCPDUMP shows the traffic reaching and leaving the machine, so it will help diagnose where the problem lies.

Comment: Oracle hosts the VPS.

Comment: is the image you posted the oracle port forwarding rule (VPS) or the firewall rule? you may need both. many systems configure the firewall when you create the DNAT rule (the VPS rule) but others do not.